# Branches available twice after GIT SVN repository conversion

Tags: git, svn, version-control-migration

I am moving a repository from SVN to git using the following tutorial: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/migrating-overview

Everything worked according to plan - I can see all branches and tags, as well as the full history. Furthermore, all names have been successfully kept.

The problem is however, that when I do a

```
    git log --all --graph  --decorate=short --oneline
```

I see all branches twice, e.g.

```
    9d70840 (branch-name, gitlab/branch-name, branch-name) Message
```

I understand the first branch (local) as well as the second: I pushed the repository to gitlab with

```
    git push gitlab --mirror
```

But what about the third? The color of the first two branches is red, the other one is green. Gitlab also sees every branch twice and shows them on the overview of the project.

I would be rather glad if anyone could explain to me what happened and how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was:

The first branch shown is local, the second one on the remote gitlab, and the third from the remote svn (from the conversion).

Instead of pushing to the gitlab remote with

```
    git push gitlab --mirror
```

one should do

```
    git push gitlab --all
    git push gitlab --tags
```

And everything will be fine.